# Как отследить изменения в форме js?

Tags: javascript

Как можно отследить изменения формы HTML (Input, Textarea), чтобы активировать кнопку Submit?
С таким условием, чтобы такая последовательность действий в поле input - не считалась изменением:
"a" -стерли - "a" - написали

Comment: невыполнимое условие, в том смысле, что вы проверку когда запускать собрались ? если по нажатию клавиш то никак, а если по переходу на другой элемент (событие change) то проблемы нет.

Comment: Horowo, uje na4al pisati rewenie, posmotrim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал такое решение,  проблема в том, что после изменении текста - событие возвращает не текущее его состояние(т-е было Oleg, стер одну букву - но событие не возвратило Ole):

```
    var params_t = {};
    var params_a = ["contacts_email", "contacts_phone", "contacts_web", "contacts_fb", "contacts_ytb", "contacts_tw", "contacts_vk"];

var btnDisable = false;
$(function() {
    $("input").keypress(function (e) {
        var id = e.target.id;
        if (inArrayCheck(params_a, id)){
            var cur_val = $(this).val();
            if(id in params_t){
                if(cur_val != params_t[id]) {
                    btnDisable = true;
                } else {
                    btnDisable = false;
                }
            } else {
                params_t[id] = cur_val;
            }

            ProfileEditor.submitActive(btnDisable);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: потому-что keypress это отменяемое событие, т.е. оно вызывается до обновления поля, ваше событие input, или keyup если не поддерживается.

Comment: А другие события? может change? c timeOut как сделать?

Comment: Еще один вопрос - как отследить, событие это по checbox или input?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так: 
У кнопок необходимых, где нужно это сделать присвой: `disabled="disabled"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formId").change(function(){
        $("#submitForm").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: Как это выполнит условие задачи

> "a" стерли - "a" написали — не считалось как изменение

Comment: Если делать сериализацию формы, то я предполагаю так:

     var obj = form.serialize();
     var serialized = JSON.stringify(obj);

На странице нет тега form.

Comment: И потом как я понимаю, при событии change, опять делать сериализацию и сравнивать с serialized

Comment: Нашел пример:
     values = '';
     values = values.concat(
            jQuery('#myform input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').map(
                    function() {
                        return {"name": this.name, "value": this.value}
                    }).get()

Answer (score 0):

Может, кэшировать состояния, которые «уже были»?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/Yeast/)

```
var Values = []
    ,$el = $('#i-text')
    ,$btn = $('#btn-s')
;

getValue = function(){ return $el.val()};
btnOn = function(){ $btn.removeAttr('disabled');}
btnOff = function(){ $btn.attr('disabled','disabled');}

Values.push( getValue());

$el.on('keyup', function(e) {
    if( -1 == Values.indexOf( getValue())) {
        Values.push( getValue());
        btnOn();
    } else {
        btnOff();
    }
});
```

Comment: А с чекбоксами как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Сформулируйте, что должно происходить с чекбоксами. Допустим, изначально он включён. Тогда можно сохранить, если его выключили. А снова включили - уже нельзя. А снова выключили - опять можно?

Comment: Например, на странице 5 чекбоксов, все отмечены. Если пользователь один из них "снимает", то кнопка submit активируется. Если же он "снимает" и тут же ставит опять, кнопка делается disable

Comment: Я думаю, это можно сделать так: Отследить, была ли установлена галочка или снята, это и будет первое состояние конкретного чекбокса. Это состояние занести в массив. При следующих - проверять есть ли такое значение в массиве и включать disable

Comment: При событии change, можно проверять e.delegateTarget.checked /true.false

Comment: в смысле вам нужно просто дизэблить сабмит, если состояние равно изначальному ? и всё ? сериализуйте его в строку да и сравнивайте.